# Unable to find a proper formula to partially match words in one column to another

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, match

I need to match words from different columns and give my input regarding the same. For example, if book names given in column A1 matches B1 along with the author names (given on C1 and D1), then it will be called a Safe match. If *only* the book name matches then Potential match and so on.

The formula I have written is given below:

```
=IFS(A1=B1,IF(C1=D1,"Safe Match",IFS(A1=B1,IF(C1<>D1,"Potential Match","No Match"))))
```

There are 2 issues with this. Firstly, I don't need an exact match. I need a partial match which this formula is not giving me. Secondly, I'm getting an error instead of "No Match".

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=IF(AND(A1=B1,C1=D1),"Safe Match",IF(AND(A1=B1,C1<>D1),"Potential Match","No Match"))
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. This is working fine and now I'm not getting the error. Thank you again.

Is there also a way I can find fuzzy match? This is still giving me exact matches. I want the formula to ignore extra words in the names. For example Central Ohio Transport should match Central Ohio Transport Ltd.

Comment: Excel doesn't really have a formula solution for fuzzy match. You could try Power Query or I believe there's a fuzzy match add-in.

Comment: You can try this [EXCEL: FUZZY MATCHING](https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/january-2021-excel-fuzzy-matching/)